# How can I avoid debugging into Boost source code in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-c++, boost, visual-studio-debugging

Is there a way to exclude boost source code (or any other) from debuging? I don't want to step into boost internal source code.

for example:

```
boost::shared_ptr<Xyz> xyz(new Xyz());
xyz->someMethod();
```

when I want to step into `Xyz::someMethod()` using F11 the debugger first steps into `boost/shared_ptr.hpp` before I get `into Xyz::someMethod()`

Comment: Step in, step out, step in again. You get the same thing with functions with class parameters that have constructors.

Comment: yes of course I can step in and step out, but i want to avoid this. In eclipse I can exclude sorce code from debuging.

Comment: Answer for VS2010: [Exclude certain projects from stepping through during debug in VS2010?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3878963/1441)

Comment: @crashmstr: That question and its answers refers to managed code (like C# or VB.NET). The situation is a little different with unmanaged C++. Find information about how to set up automatic stepping-over here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andypennell/archive/2004/02/06/69004.aspx

Comment: Put in a breakpoint and hit continue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to automatically avoiding stepping into certain functions in Visual Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/626744/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-avoiding-stepping-into-certain-functions-in-visu)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Launch `regedit` and navigate to the following key:

Under a 32bit OS:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\NativeDE\StepOver`

Under a 64bit OS:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\NativeDE\StepOver`

Create a new string value there. Name it as you wish. Enter this as a content:

`boost\:\:.*`

(You need to restart Visual Studio.)

Comment: if you are using Visual Studio Express the key is `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VCExpress\10.0\NativeDE\StepOver`

Comment: This sounds like a nice solution, but today our helpful IT administrators just decided that launching `regedit` would be to dangerous for us noobs :-(   -> +1 anyway

Answer (score 3):

### For Visual Studio 2012:

As described [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/andypennell/2004/02/06/how-to-not-step-into-functions-using-the-visual-c-debugger), this information is stored in the file `C:\Program Files[ (x86)]\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers\default.natstepfilter`

For boost::shared_ptr, this here has helped:

```
<Function><Name>boost::shared_ptr&lt;.*</Name><Action>NoStepInto</Action></Function>
```

Comment: Works for VS 2015 too. Thanks!

Comment: VS 2017 this file can be found under: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers`
Thanks!

Comment: And "<Function><Name>boost::*</Name><Action>NoStepInto</Action></Function>" to get rid of all boost files step into.