# How to not step into shared_ptr in xcode

Tags: xcode, lldb

Similar to this question:
[How can I avoid debugging into Boost source code in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9037534/how-can-i-avoid-debugging-into-boost-source-code-in-visual-studio)

But how can I do it in Xcode?

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: Good question, and I would love to know the answer! I have added the lldb tag, because that is the debugger used by recent Xcode versions.

Comment: I'm guessing that the debugger steps in to these because they're inlined. Anyone think that's a good guess?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The key is the lldb setting `target.process.thread.step-avoid-regexp`.  On my Mac, this had the default value `^std::`.  You might want to check it on your setup by entering lldb and typing `settings show target.process.thread.step-avoid-regexp`.  Anyway, what you can do is edit ~/.lldbinit, creating it if it does not yet exist, and add a line like

```
settings set target.process.thread.step-avoid-regexp ^(std::|boost::shared_ptr)
```

This keeps the previous behavior of not stepping into std:: stuff, and also does not step into shared_ptr.

Comment: Great. Thanks. Not much of a mac user, so I'll try to figure out how to do this.

Comment: You saved the day

Comment: Where do I place ```.lldbinit``` on Windows?

Comment: @T.J.Evers, are you sure you're using lldb on Windows?  It's not even fully implemented on Windows yet.