# CLion Restrict Debugging Step Into to Project Functions only

Tags: c++, ide, clion

Is there a way in CLion 2017 to step into project source files only whilst debugging a program?

For example in the code segment below,

`function1 (boost::doSomething())`

I have a function from an external library (e.g. `boost`) which I don't want the debugger to go into while I step through the program.

Is there a setting that forces CLion to skip stepping into any code from an external library?

Comment: This feature is not implemented yet, please follow for the updates: [CPP-10876 Debugger: Smart Step Into (Step into specific function)](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-10876)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment above, the feature is not yet implemented.

Comment: If it helps somebody, method breakpoints may provide an alternative. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/types-of-breakpoints.html#method_breakpoint

Answer (score 9):

If CLion is using **gdb** for it's debugger then you can create the file `~/.gdbinit` and add the following to ignore all functions in `boost::` namespace.

```
skip -rfu "boost::.*"
```

As another example, you can also add the following line to skip all the header files in include/bits (like unique_pointer.h).

```
skip -gfile include/bits/*.h
```

More info on `skip` options at [Debugging with GDB: Skipping Over Functions and Files](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Skipping-Over-Functions-and-Files.html) and in this useful answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42985979/255961.

See this link for how to do something similar if CLion is using **lldb** - [How to not step into shared_ptr in xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15556438/how-to-not-step-into-shared-ptr-in-xcode).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
auto result = boost::doSomething();
function1 (result);
```

Comment: This would not skip the first statement while stepping into the code while debugging.

Comment: @user3079474 If no exceptions are thrown from `doSomething`, you just step over it while debugging. What else makes debugger step into `doSomething` ?

Comment: This helps in one specific instance, but is not a general solution. I can't pull out all `std::`, `boost::` etc. calls into their own lines across the entire codebase just to make it easier to step over them. It would be a huge amount of work and decrease readability by blowing up the line count simple algorithms get smeared across.